# How does ballast pnp regulator work?

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, pnp, ballast

I saw this ballast regulator on internet. On this scheme NPN based, I easily understood the 
Vout = Vref - Vbe.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkD8S2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But I don't understand this kind of ballast used in the [MC9S12ZVLRM](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/reference-manuals/MC9S12ZVLRM.pdf) (page 677)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPukXC.png)</sup>

How do I pick the right transistor ?

Comment: Please include a part number, we can't help you understand it if you don't tell us what it is. Secondly, read the datasheet, then ask a *specific question* about what you don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Unfortunately for yourself, this isn't a free design consultancy where you ask short questions and get long custom-made replies. People will be happy to help if you've written a detailed question that shows how you've gone as far as you can on your own. Again, welcome.

Comment: Sorry i didn't want to be that rude. I am wondering how this ballast stuff works. I didn't understood with what I could find  with google... I edited my question. Does it fit this exchange site standards ?

Comment: Try Google LDO voltage regulator using PNP http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/5413598800_1491237768.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PNP ballast transistor also works in linear region, just same as the NPN type, the difference is the ib current controlling mothod. The first figure is controlled by emitter resistor feedback, and the second one is controlled by the Vcontrol pin. Please refer [NXP Forum:How to choice hFE of ballast transistor](https://community.nxp.com/thread/486299)